# Pipe SED output to mysql

Tags: mysql, sed

I'm an trying to pipe output data directly from sed into mysql by doing something like:

`sed "s/url\/uct\/video/url\/uct\/video/g" 2019-11-25T0330-main.sql.gz | mysql opencast`

Is this possible? I keep running out of space and therefore piping it straight into mysql would be ideal (instead of running sed independently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
gunzip main.sql.gz | sed 's@url/uct/video@url/uct/video@g' | mysql opencast
```

Note if you use a different char besides `/` for `sed`s `s/str/rep/` you can avoid having to escape `/` chars that are part of the `sub/repl` patterns. For some OS's (besided Linux) users, you may need to escape the first use of the alternate delimit character, like `sed '\@sub@repl@`

*And if you are using the `-i` option for `sed`, it doesn't make sense in the context of reading input from a pipe* ;-)

IHTH